# Google Maps API 2 MapView Not Updating

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm displaying a Google Maps API v2 MapView in an Android app, but it's curiously not updating properly in a consistent fashion. I'm using the GPS to update the map position (tried both LocationManager and LocationClient) and although the map moves to the position, about fifty percent of the time either the street name layer fails to update or there's a fuzzy/blurry section that fails to update--until I do a manual drag (scroll) of the map.  Then the entire map updates instantly. I've stripped out a lot of the processing in the app to see if I was somehow preventing a refresh, but it didn't make a difference.

I inserted a mapView.invalidate() call in onCameraChange but that oddly seemed to make the problem occur more readily (although still not 100% of the time).

I am implementing all of the Activity callbacks as required by MapView.

Has anyone encountered a problem like this with Google Map API v2 on Android? If so, did you identify the cause and how did you solve it?

Comment: Have you checked your internet connection? It has to keep pulling that data.

Comment: A network bottleneck was one of the first things I considered. I think the solution is the one below, the CancelableCallback. Thanks.

Comment: I recommand you Polaris2 as third part library which is very useful for all this kind of features in-app :) 
You can use danny's solution to it and you'll have a lot of features really helpful
https://github.com/cyrilmottier/Polaris2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to let the map breathe so to speak.

Use `animateCamera` with a `CancelableCallback` then when the animation is completed you'll get a call back to `onFinish()` start the next animation.

```
public class KmlReader extends ActionBarActivity implements
    CancelableCallback {


@Override
public void onFinish() {
    startAnimation(); // start next map movement
}


@Override
public void onCancel() {
    //Called when user interacts with the map while it is moving.
}


public void startAnimation(){

cameraPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition();    
LatLng ll = new LatLng(expectedLocation.getLatitude(),
                    expectedLocation.getLongitude());
            cb.zoom(cameraPosition.zoom)
            // previous camera tilt
                    .tilt(cameraPosition.tilt)
                    // new expected destination
                    .target(ll)
                    // north up or heading view
                    .bearing((isHeading) ? bearing : 0f);
            cameraPosition = cb.build();
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
            mMap.animateCamera(update, working_interval, this);
}
```

*** Edit this is the code I'm working on now.***
it uses an asynctask for the calcuations.  I've given it a walking test but haven't tested it in a vehicle.

```
private static CameraPosition currentCameraPosition;
private static com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition.Builder cameraPositionBuilder;
private volatile CameraUpdate nextCameraUpdate;
// updates 
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2500;
// fastest 
private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2500;
private static int working_interval = 5000; 
private volatile boolean isAnimating;


// Define the callback method that receives location updates
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("test", Boolean.toString(isAnimating)  +" onlocation");
    currentCameraPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition();

    NewCameraUpdateTask newCameraUpdateTask = new NewCameraUpdateTask();

// This task must run async
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    newCameraUpdateTask.executeOnExecutor(
            AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, location);
} else {
    newCameraUpdateTask.execute(location);
}
    // speed display
    setMetersPerSecond(location.getSpeed());
}

// create a newCameraUpdate to move the map with
private class NewCameraUpdateTask extends
        AsyncTask<Location, Void, CameraUpdate> {

    @Override
    protected CameraUpdate doInBackground(Location... params) {
        Location workingLocation = null;
        CameraUpdate newCameraUpdate = null;

        float bearing = 0f;
        float speed = 0f;

        for (Location mlocation : params) {
            speed = mlocation.getSpeed();

            // camera position is saved before the start of each animation.
            LatLng ll;

        if (!mlocation.hasBearing() || speed == 0) {
            workingLocation = mlocation;
            // previous bearing
        } else {
            // current bearing
            bearing = mlocation.getBearing();
            // calculate the age of the location
            // atempt for animation to end a little bit past when
            // the
            // next
            // location arrives.
            // (location.getSpeed()m/s)(1/1000 interval seconds)(
            // 1/1000
            // km/m)
            // (1/6371 radians/km) = radians/6371000000.0
            double expectedDistance = working_interval / 6371000000.0
                    * speed;

            // latitude in Radians
            double currentLatitude = Math.toRadians(mlocation
                    .getLatitude());
            // longitude in Radians
            double currentlongitude = Math.toRadians(mlocation
                    .getLongitude());

            double calcBearing = Math.toRadians(bearing);

            // the camera position is needed so I can put in the
            // previous camera bearing when the location has no
            // bearing. This should prevent the map from
            // zooming to north when the device stops moving.

            // calculate the expected latitude and longitude based
            // on
            // staring
            // location
            // , bearing, and distance
            double sincurrentLatitude = Math.sin(currentLatitude);
            double coscurrentLatitude = Math.cos(currentLatitude);
            double cosexpectedDistance = Math.cos(expectedDistance);
            double sinexpectedDistance = Math.sin(expectedDistance);

            double expectedLatitude = Math.asin(sincurrentLatitude
                    * cosexpectedDistance + coscurrentLatitude
                    * sinexpectedDistance * Math.cos(calcBearing));
            double a = Math.atan2(
                    Math.sin(calcBearing) * sinexpectedDistance
                            * coscurrentLatitude,
                    cosexpectedDistance - sincurrentLatitude
                            * Math.sin(expectedLatitude));
            double expectedLongitude = currentlongitude + a;
            expectedLongitude = (expectedLongitude + PI3) % PI2 - PI;

            // convert to degrees for the expected destination
            double expectedLongitudeDestination = Math
                    .toDegrees(expectedLongitude);
            double expectedLatitudeDestination = Math
                    .toDegrees(expectedLatitude);

            mlocation.setLatitude(expectedLatitudeDestination);
            mlocation.setLongitude(expectedLongitudeDestination);
            workingLocation = mlocation;

        }
        break;
    }

    if (workingLocation != null) {
        if (workingLocation.hasBearing()) {
            bearing = workingLocation.getBearing();
        } else {
            bearing = currentCameraPosition.bearing;
        }
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(workingLocation.getLatitude(),
                workingLocation.getLongitude());
        cameraPositionBuilder.zoom(currentCameraPosition.zoom)
        // previous camera tilt
                .tilt(currentCameraPosition.tilt)
                // new expected destination
                .target(ll)
                // north up or heading view
                .bearing((isHeading) ? bearing : 0f);
        newCameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPositionBuilder.build());
    }

    return newCameraUpdate;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(CameraUpdate result) {
    Log.d("test", Boolean.toString(isAnimating) + " onPostExecute");
    if (result != null) {
        nextCameraUpdate = result;
        // stop the currently playing animation
        // there is a new one ready to start
        if (isAnimating) {
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.stopAnimation();
            }
        }
        // start the next animation
        startAnimation();
        Log.d("test", Boolean.toString(isAnimating)  +" onPostExecuteComplete");
    }


}
}


// called when map animation has been canceled
@Override
public void onCancel() {
    Log.d("test", Boolean.toString(isAnimating)  +" oncancel");
    isAnimating = false;
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    Log.d("test", Boolean.toString(isAnimating)  +" onfinish");
    isAnimating = false;
    startAnimation();

    // call to start saved animation.
}

private void startAnimation() {
    Log.d("test", Boolean.toString(isAnimating)  +" startAnimation");
    if (action_track) {
        if (isAnimating) {
            return;
        }
        if (nextCameraUpdate == null) {
            return;
        }
        // abort if animating
        isAnimating = true;
        CameraUpdate animateCameraUpdate = nextCameraUpdate;
        nextCameraUpdate = null;
        mMap.animateCamera(animateCameraUpdate, working_interval, this);
        Log.d("test", Boolean.toString(isAnimating)  +" startanimateCamera");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good stuff, never seen this implementation

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. Now another tricky part: how to start and stop the animation based on asynchronous location updates. Sometimes location updates come in several times a second, sometimes once in a blue moon if you're not moving. Gatekeeper flag cleared in onFinish?  (Tried this, not yet working.) Location queue of size one? Is there an example out there somewhere?

Comment: Okay, I got it. Using a AtomicBoolean as a gatekeeper flag seems to do the trick.

Comment: Here's the tricky part.  I can move the map with the coords at dead center and it's acceptable movement but I need some trig wizzard to show me how to move the map with the coords near the bottom of the map?

Comment: I'm posting my whole implementation.  It was failing today but I might not have had the correct apk on my phone.

Comment: Positioning near the bottom of the map is complicated but it's a matter determining the distance represented on the screen at the current zoom level and adding a fraction of that distance in the heading direction. Use that position in your camera update.

Comment: It looks like onFinish doesn't get called if a cameraPosition object is equal to the previous one. See https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5208. If you're setting a flag in onFinish you need to compare your cameraPosition to the last one to see if they're identical.

Comment: My problem is I don't get calls to onLocationChanged if the camera is animating.  I'm using google play services for locations.

Comment: I posted some new code haven't given it a drive test yet but walking down the driveway and back it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is having this issue, the key is to keep the `animateCamera` call's animation duration less than the frequency with which you are calling the `animateCamera` method.

For example if you call `animateCamera` every `1000ms` set tha animate camera duration to be less than that.

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, ZOOM_LEVEL), 900, null)
```

If your `animateCamera` call is not being called at a constant time, then danny117's answer to use the callback to trigger the next camera update will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from danny117's solution, I found a simpler solution.
I set the location request update for each 5 millisecond and I set the animate camera duration to be 2.5 ms. Problem solved