# Low detailed Google Maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing a simple app on Android to track my position on a map.
I noticed that as long as I stay in the same area where I was when I started the application, everything works fine. When I leave this area (about 500x500 m) the camera follow my movement, but the underlying map becomes more and more poorly detailed, the names of the streets disappear and the streets themeselves become blurred. After a while, the map returns at the original level of detail, and when I move again the aforementioned behavior keep showing.

Why this happens? Is there a way to avoid this? Thanks

Comment: Is this due to slow connection? Does this happen if you use google's own map application?

Comment: When I use google maps everything works fine.

Comment: Are you using an old version of library? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691604/google-map-hang-in-slow-speed-internet-connection-android

Comment: No I'm using the most recent library. Maybe the problem resides in the way I move the camera on the map? Everytime I get a new location (about one new location per second) I move the camera. Is it possible that all these little movements cause the map not to update properly?

Comment: In addition I noticed that when i touch the screen, ad example to zoom in, the map becomes high detailed immediately

Comment: Seems the same problem if you could update the data instantly with a touch event - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998144/google-maps-api-2-mapview-not-updating

Comment: Yes, the problem is the same, but I did not succeed in making the example work. How come that a simple thing like this is so difficult to achieve?